# making a ball roll with drivers

Tags: animation, rigging, drivers

I want to "rig" a ball, so that it looks like it's rolling on the ground as I move it around.

So far I've parented the ball to an empty and set up drivers for the X and Y rotation, so that the ball will rotate along the y axis if I move it on the x axis, (and vice versa for the x-axis rotation.)
Well now, the rotation is fine if the ball rolls only along either the X or Y axis. As soon as it goes diagonal, the ball will rotate incorrectly.

I've uploaded the .blend file with what I've set up so far...
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35956

I've tried messing around with the transform space settings (local space, world space etc.) and also tried to set up a third driver for the Z rotation but I couldn't get it to work, so at this point I can't think of any solution to this, but I hope you guys can help me out :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with combining Euler rotations from different axes is that the order of rotations is significant. For example, rotating along the y-axis then the x-axis is not equivalent to rotating along the x-axis then the y-axis.

*One way monkey looks to the right the other it points down*
[image: Difference between rotating along y-axis then x-axis and x-axis then y-axis]

Since the final rotation is dependent upon the order of individual rotations, we are unable to absolutely determine the rotation from the x and y coordinates. However, if we assume that rotation only occurs perpendicular to displacement, we can approximate the appearance of an object rolling by rotating it when the location changes.

For this approach, we store the object's previous position in order to calculate the difference in location. We create a rotation matrix with the magnitude for the angle and the normal as its axis. Then, we combine the rotation matrix and extract its Euler rotation. The script makes a [modal operator](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.types.Operator.html#modal-execution) which rolls the active object when it is called.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector

class RollOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "transform.roll"
    bl_label = "Roll active object"

    def execute(self, context):
        dx = self.dx / 100
        dy = self.dy / 100

        matrix = Matrix.Rotation((dx**2 + dy**2)**.5, 4, Vector((-dy, dx, 0)))
        matrix *= context.object.matrix_world
        context.object.rotation_euler = matrix.to_euler('XYZ')
        context.object.location.x += dx
        context.object.location.y += dy
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':  # Apply
            self.dx = event.mouse_x - event.mouse_prev_x
            self.dy = event.mouse_y - event.mouse_prev_y            
            self.execute(context)
        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':  # Confirm
            return {'FINISHED'}
        elif event.type in ('RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'):  # Cancel
            context.object.location = self.location
            context.object.rotation_euler = self.rotation_euler
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        rotation = context.object.rotation_euler
        location = context.object.location
        self.location = location[0], location[1], location[2]
        self.rotation_euler = rotation[0], rotation[1], rotation[2]        
        self.dx = 0
        self.dy = 0        
        self.execute(context)
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


bpy.utils.register_class(RollOperator)
```

After running the script, add a shortcut key to start it. This one used <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> in the 3D View.

[image: Shortcut key]

With the operator, the monkey rolls as it moves.

[image: Monkey rolling around]

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, your script really helps!
I got it to work within my scene now (I'm very new to python so it took me a while to figure out how to get the script to only affect the one object I want instead of just any selected object, but now everything seems to work, thanks again!

Comment: I've got another issue with this now: When the script is running I cannot use the cycles viewport IPR render mode, since for some reason blender thinks it needs to update all the time. The viewport will just flicker, switching between 1-2 samples since it just keeps re-rendering all the time.

Is this a bug, or might the script be doing something that makes blender think there are changes being made in the scene even though the scene is actually static?

Comment: @HansGruber Rewrote script to correct the issues

Comment: @David this is a great script!  However, I am unable to keyframe it...is this possible?