# How do I properly add a shortcut key to run a script.?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, shortcut

I'm having trouble running this script I found on the exchange. how do I go about running it? My efforts are:

- open blender,
- delete default scene,
- add a cube,
- switch to scripting workspace,
- create new text data block,
- paste script, and
- run.

Nothing happens when I move the cube only a bpy.ops.text.run_script() in the console. How do I add the shortcut key needed to run the script.

Here is the [original post with script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30574/making-a-ball-roll-with-drivers)

Version 3.0
cycles
windows

ZERO coding experience

Comment: @MartyFouts Shift-Q doesn't seem to work. How would I add the entry to the keymap?

Answer (score 1):

Before I show you how to add the keymap entry, here's a changed script that installs the keymap automatically.

Paste and run this version so you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>Q</kbd> to run it.  However, I've also added step by step instructions for adding the shortcut by hand, if you want to stick to the original code.

EDIT: I've modified the script to be closer to how the original script performs but I didn't have time to figure out what broke between releases so it's not exactly the same.

### Modified Script with keymap entry

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector

mode_keymap = None

class RollOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "transform.roll"
    bl_label = "Roll active object"
    def execute(self, context):
        dx = self.dx / 100
        dy = self.dy / 100
        #matrix = Matrix.Rotation((dx**2 + dy**2)**.5, 4, Vector((-dy, dx, 0)))
        #matrix *= context.object.matrix_world
        context.object.rotation_euler.x += dx*pi/4
        context.object.rotation_euler.y += dy*pi/4
        context.object.location.x += dx
        context.object.location.y += dy
        return {'FINISHED'}
    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':  # Apply
            self.dx = event.mouse_x - event.mouse_prev_x
            self.dy = event.mouse_y - event.mouse_prev_y            
            self.execute(context)
        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':  # Confirm
            return {'FINISHED'}
        elif event.type in ('RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'):  # Cancel
            context.object.location = self.location
            context.object.rotation_euler = self.rotation_euler
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        rotation = context.object.rotation_euler
        location = context.object.location
        self.location = location[0], location[1], location[2]
        self.rotation_euler = rotation[0], rotation[1], rotation[2]        
        self.dx = 0
        self.dy = 0        
        self.execute(context)
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


bpy.utils.register_class(RollOperator)

key_config = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
if key_config:
    key_map = key_config.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
    key_entry = key_map.keymap_items.new("transform.roll",
                                        type='Q',
                                        value='PRESS',
                                        shift=True,
    )
    mode_keymap = (key_map, key_entry)
```

### How to add the entry by hand

- Edit Preferences, and go to the Keymap tab
- Scroll down until you see the *3D View* tab.  Click the arrow to open it.
- Scroll down until you see the *Object Mode* tab.  Click the arrow to open it.
- Scroll down until you see the *Object Mode (Global)* tab.  Click the arrow to open it.  You'll now be nested 3 deep.
- Scroll down until you see the *Add New button*.  Click it.  That will add an entry labeled "none" just above the button.  Click the arrow to open it.
- type `transform.roll` into the box that has "none" in it.  Change the `A` to a `Q` (don't shift, just click the `A` and type `q`) and click the `shift` button. The edit box should now look like this:

[image: Final result]

Now you can run the script with <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>Q</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth response I learned a lot. unfortunately, the object doesn't roll when I use the shortcut. when I press shift Q it just moves, as if I just grabbed it moving it along the axis. no rotation :(. I tried troubleshooting different blender versions and both scripts but to no avail. Am i missing an add-on in pref?

Comment: You're not missing anything.  The script was written for an earlier version of Blender and it looks like it needs an update.  When I have some time I'll take a look at what the update should be and modify the script in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I look forward to it.

Comment: did you find a workaround?

Comment: @mehnoy not yet.  Big holiday over the weekend meant entertaining family.

Comment: enjoy the holiday

Comment: @mehnoy This script now sort of does what the original did.  I kind of like it better.  You can "tune" it by changing the two Euler related equations.